# JSF String Replace Using Regex

Tags: regex, string, jsf, replace

I have a string that is output as a date:

```
#{bean.someString}
```

I want to take that string and manipulate it using regular expressions like so:

- original string: "11/22"
- expected string: "22/11"

I have tried to use a regular expression using f:replace, such as:

```
#{fn:replace(bean.someString, "(.*?)/(.*?)", "$2/$1")}
```

But it comes out as:

- actual string: "/1122"

Anyone know how I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too sleepy to search it now, but there are ways to parse datetimes with sdf in JSF. If nobody has answered tomorrow I will give you a sample from my code.

Comment: What if this wasn't a date/time, but just a string that needed manipulation? Thanks!

Comment: Also, change `.*` by `.+`. The first means that the first group may be all of the string (the second being empty). By doing `.+`, the regex **must** recognize that there is something behind the `/` (I bet that is the failure with that specific regex, although for datetime I advise dateformatter)

Comment: That got me this far: `2/112`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer (after much tribulation).

Because I have a fixed set of characters to traverse I can use the following to get the correct replacement:

```
#{fn:replace(bean.someString, "(.{2})/(.{2})", "$2/$1")}
```

Craziness that normal regex doesn't work here.